# why setAttribute('href') need twice in IE?

Tags: javascript, axios

Today i read axios score and in 'isURLSameOrigin.js' , i watch some code,

```js
(function standardBrowserEnv () {
      var msie = /(msie|trident)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
      var urlParsingNode = document.createElement('a')
      var originURL

      function resolveURL (url) {
        var href = url
  
        // this is important
        if (msie) {
          urlParsingNode.setAttribute('href', href)
          href = urlParsingNode.href
        }

        urlParsingNode.setAttribute('href', href)

        return {
          href: urlParsingNode.href,
          protocol: urlParsingNode.protocol ? urlParsingNode.protocol.replace(/:$/, '') : '',
          host: urlParsingNode.host,
          search: urlParsingNode.search ? urlParsingNode.search.replace(/^\?/, '') : '',
          hash: urlParsingNode.hash ? urlParsingNode.hash.replace(/^#/, '') : '',
          hostname: urlParsingNode.hostname,
          port: urlParsingNode.port,
          pathname: (urlParsingNode.pathname.charAt(0) === '/')
            ? urlParsingNode.pathname
            : '/' + urlParsingNode.pathname
        }
      }

      originURL = resolveURL(window.location.href)

      return function isURLSameOrigin (requestURL) {
        var parsed = (utils.isString(requestURL)) ? resolveURL(requestURL) : requestURL
        return (parsed.protocol === originURL.protocol &&
            parsed.host === originURL.host)
      }
    })()
```

it do something difficult for IE .it setAttribute('href',href) twice. i just want know why? it's important, it looks not useful.

Comment: But the next row code is  ` href = urlParsingNode.href ` , if i just set attribute name, in this row , i just can get undefined for href.But it works.

Comment: [Current version of the code on github](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/b8f6f5049cf3da8126a184b6b270316402b5b374/lib/helpers/isURLSameOrigin.js) says `// IE needs attribute set twice to normalize properties`. So it's *to normalize properties*. As to why IE would need this, probably an implementation quirk that only them has the secret.